# Виджет Cmenu: как расположить html-код у label?

Tags: php, yii, html

Доброго времени суток знатоки! Есть маленькая проблемка, решение которой никак не могу найти.
Есть обычное меню в Cmenu в layouts/main.php. Есть строка вида

```
array('label'=>Yii::t('kaz',"Регистрация промо кода"), 'url'=>array('/members/index')),
```

Как вы, наверное, поняли `yii::t` ведет на файл, где лежит перевод 'Регистрация промо кода'=>'Регистрация промо кода'. Так вот этот Yii никак не хочет считать его, как html- код! А мне очень нужно.

Кто-нибудь знает, как это можно сделать? Знаю, что вопрос элеметарный... но что-то никак не решу его. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поддержки HTML-кода в надписях нужно отключить экранирование HTML-сущностей, указав `'encodeLabel'=>false:`

Comment: Вооооо, спасибо большое ) то, что доктор прописал )

Comment: Не за что) все это написано в документации - не нужно лениться а читать ее и изучать